# PHP+Imagick: How to apply a gradient to background to part of an image?

Tags: php, imagemagick, alphablending

This might seems like a duplicated question, but I couldn't find exactly this scenario. Might be wrong though.

My problem is, say I have a square, $square, of 100x100 pixels inside a canvas of 150x150. Background is transparent.

I cloned the square and then I cropped the part I needed to work on ($detail).

I need to apply a gradient, top to bottom, on  $detail so that the top part is around 60% white-transparent to a 100% transparent at the bottom.

Then, to compose $detail over $image.

I can't use convert, only php imagick functions.

Thanks in advance!
Will

Answer (score 0):

`convert` has a special creation operator in recent versions for producing gradients, simply called `gradient:` - they are implemented as [pseudo image formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/formats.html#pseudo).

Usage of the [`gradient:`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#gradient) operator can get quite complex if you want non-vertical gradients or with transparency, so read the documentation.  Be aware the underlying version of Image Magick will make a difference to how you have to go about it.

You can create pseudo-format images, using the IMagick operator: [`Imagick::newPseudoImage()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/imagick.newpseudoimage.php)

Once you have the gradient at the right size, you can compose it with your `$detail` image.

Generally, my tip with using things like IMagick, is to get the command right using `convert` first and then translate it to the interface.